# Filter list items based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, list

I have list item as below:

```
[{"category1": None, "category2": None, "category3": None, "Name": "one"},  {"category1": "AAA", "category2": None, "category3": None, "Name": "two"}  {"category1": "AAA", "category2": "BBB", "category3": None, "Name": "three"},  {"category1": "AAA", "category2": "BBB", "category3": "CCC", "Name": "four"}]
```

and need select the items based on the below condition

- category1: None, category2: None, category3: None -> ResultantName=one
- category1:AAA, category2: None, category3: None -> ResultantName=two
- category1: AAA, category2: BBB, category3: None -> ResultantName=three
- category1: AAA, category2: BBB, category3: CCC -> ResultantName=four
- category1: XXX, category2: None, category3: None -> ResultantName=one
- category1: AAA, category2: XXX, category3:   None -> ResultantName=two
- category1: AAA, category2: BBB, category3: XXX -> ResultantName=three

  ```
  categories = {'category1':'AAA','category2':'XXX','category3':None}
  ```

for template in list(templates):

```
    if categories.get('category1'):
        if template.get('category1') and template.get('category1') !=categories.get('category1'):
            templates.remove(template)
            continue
    elif categories.get('category1') is None:
        if template.get('category1') is not None:
            templates.remove(template)
            continue

    if categories.get('category2'):
        if template.get('category2') and template.get('category2') !=categories.get('category2'):
            templates.remove(template)
            continue
    elif categories.get('category2') is None:
        if template.get('category2') is not None:
            templates.remove(template)
            continue
    if categories.get('category3'):
        if template.get('category3') and template.get('category3') !=categories.get('category3'):
            templates.remove(template)
            continue
    elif categories.get('category3') is None:
        if template.get('category3') is not None:
            templates.remove(template)
            continue
```

but this does not work for all my conditions.

Please help with this.

Comment: What conditions does it fail for, and how exactly does it fail?

Comment: Did you wanted to filter the items list based on the first condition (category1: None, category2: None, category3: None -> one), then the second ..etc ?

Comment: For each condition i want to get the resultant Name as answer For condition category1:AAA, category2: None, category3: None  answer=two

Comment: Would this help: # the_list = [{"category1": None, "category2": None, "category3": None, "Name": "one"}, ....]
 filtered = filter(lambda elem: elem["category1"] is None and elem["category2"] is None and elem["Name"] is "one", the_list)

Comment: We should use only categories for our condition and not name field, name is just for reference. Consider condition category1:AAA, category2: XXX, category3: None. Here XXX is any undefined value this should match with condition category1: AAA, category2:None, category3: None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dictionary where each entry is a condition: The key will be a tuple with the values for the categories (`category1`, `category2`, `category3`). The entry value then will be your target variable (`Name`)
e.g:

```py
names['AAA', 'BBB', None] # "three"
names[None, None, None] # "one"
```

assuming there is a variable `conditions` that is the list variable you wrote in the first code snippet, you can build the dictionary `names` with something like this:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

keys = map(itemgetter('category1', 'category2', 'category3'), conditions)
values = map(itemgetter('Name'), conditions)
names = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

To access the dictionary via `get`, you need to pass a tuple with the categories explicitly:

```py
names.get(('AAA', 'BBB', None))
```

EDIT:
The next function `get_name(...)` is equivalent to `names[...]` but it replaces category 'XXX' values with None

```py
def get_name(*args):
    categories = tuple(map(lambda arg: arg if arg != 'XXX' else None, args))
    return names.get(categories)

get_name('AAA', 'BBB', 'XXX') # 'two'
get_name('AAA', 'BBB', None) # 'two'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's very near to my solution, but from your example i get output as {(None, None, None): 'one', ('AAA', None, None): 'two', ('AAA', 'BBB', None): 'three', ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'): 'four'} but XXX case is not handled, where XXX is undefined in my list variable, how do i handle this

Comment: You mean 'XXX' is equivalent to None in your case?

Comment: If anything is undefined in the list we should consider as equivalent to None

Comment: Edited response

Comment: This works well, but'XXX' is any undefined value we should not hard code like arg != 'XXX'. XXX can be any undefined value, it may become YYY as well So please help as how to handle for undfined value, any undefined value should be considered as None

Comment: Define what is a undefined value

Comment: Anything not there is my first defined list is undefined value           
[{"category1": None, "category2": None, "category3": None, "Name": "one"},  {"category1": "AAA", "category2": None, "category3": None, "Name": "two"}  {"category1": "AAA", "category2": "BBB", "category3": None, "Name": "three"},  {"category1": "AAA", "category2": "BBB", "category3": "CCC", "Name": "four"}]
We dont know wat value these categories have, if anything other than these categories value is called undefined value and it should be considered as None

Comment: You mean a undefined value is any value that is not one of: 'AAA' , 'BBB', 'CCC' ?

Comment: Yes, correct, if the list items dont have that value it is undefined

Comment: Instead of ```arg != 'XXX'```, replace it with ```arg not in all_categories``` . Define the variable ```all_categories``` as  a list with all the possible categories you have. ```('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')``` or ```set(chain.from_iterable(names.keys())) ```

Comment: Thanks Thats perfect

Comment: Still not correct, category1: AAA, category2: BBB, category3: BBB, here from my initial list BBB is undefined for Category3, it should be replaced with None, Actually we should replace w.r.t category values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197054/discussion-between-victor-ruiz-and-santosh).